# how to change position of icon in bottom navigation bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, icons, flutter-bottomnavigation

I want to build something like this

[image]

What I build so far is this, but I can not move it up

[image]

I tired using stack to move the icon up but it does not work

my code

```
   BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  label: 'AppStrings.home',
                  icon: ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage(AppImages.home),
                    size: 35.sp,
                  ),
                  activeIcon: Stack(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 68,
                        height: 68,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: AppColors.secondaryColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: AppColors.whiteColor,
                            width: 3
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
```

Comment: You can wrap the icon button with padding and add a bottom offset, but that won't likely give you the design you want, you probably want to build custom navigation that will give you more control. There are a few packages that do this already: https://pub.dev/packages/molten_navigationbar_flutter  I suggest following their pattern: https://github.com/AymanProjects/Molten_NavigationBar_Flutter/blob/master/lib/molten_navigationbar_flutter.dart

Comment: here's another example: https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar where they paint the bar as they wish: https://github.com/rafalbednarczuk/curved_navigation_bar/blob/master/lib/src/nav_custom_painter.dart

Answer (score 1):

You can use FloatingActionButton but unfortunately will be not a good choice check [this](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/77/how-to-set-notched-floating-action-button-in-bottom-navigation-bar/) because you want to make it at any place you want, so the best way is to build with your custom widget by using stack
1 first stack if where the max height with house button height.
2 second stack is the normal bottom bar.

also you must know how to deal with Positioned widget which will help you.
read [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/flutter-stack) might help you,also to create [create custom navigation bar](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-custom-bottom-navigation-bar/) .

and as final way to do it use package [flutter gems](https://fluttergems.dev/bottom-navigation-bar/) website will help you.

Comment: is there a a way to do it without using third party libraries